# controlling the expandability of list using a checkbox in parent row

Tags: android, checkbox

I am trying to create an expandable list that has a textview and a checkbox in parent row and has a single child row with multiple child items in it. I want to control the expansion and contraction of the parent row with a checkbox being checked and unchecked respectively, which i am failing to achieve. I am using 3 XMLs: activity_main.xml that has an expandable list; list_group.xml (parent row) that has a textview and a checkbox; list_item.xml (child row) that has two textviews.
Here is my code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
CheckBox cb_group;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    //    cb_group.setChecked(true);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    cb_group = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_group);
    cb_group.setChecked(isExpanded);


    return convertView;
}


@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

The main activity code is:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
CheckBox cb_group;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

//   cb_group=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.layout.cb_group);
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Blackberry Curve");
    listDataHeader.add("Samsung");
    listDataHeader.add("IOS");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();
    one.add("Curve 3110");

    List<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();
    two.add("Galaxy Ace");


    List<String> three = new ArrayList<String>();
    three.add("Iphone 5");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), one); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), two);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), three);
}
```

Comment: Whats problem ?? Please be clear.

Comment: I am unable to perform the action of checkbox to expand and collapse the list.With the above code, the list expands on the click of parent row and simultaneously the checkbox gets checked, but I want that it should expand only when the checkbox is checked and collapse when checkbox is unchecked.